# link xml data by element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml file

```
<musicLibrary>
<compilation id="C01" title="Best of something">
    <title no="1" name="firstOne">
        <fileID>F01</fileID>
    </title>
    <title no="2" name="secondOne">
        <fileID>F02</fileID>
    </title>
    <title no="3" name="thirdOne">
        <fileID>F03</fileID>
    </title>
    <title no="4" name="fourthOne">
        <fileID>F04</fileID>
        <fileID>F05</fileID>
    </title>
</compiltion>
<compilation id="C02" title="Best of another thing">
    ...
</compilation>

<files>
    <file id="F01">
        <filename>soundFile8.mp3</filename>
        <size>3.456</size>
        <length>3.23</length>
    </file>
    <file id="F02">
        <filename>soundFile2.mp3</filename>
        <size>3.456</size>
        <length>3.23</length>
    </file>
    <file id="F03">
        <filename>soundFile7.mp3</filename>
        <size>3.456</size>
        <length>3.23</length>
    </file>
    <file id="F04">
        <filename>soundFile5.mp3</filename>
        <size>3.456</size>
        <length>3.23</length>
    </file>
    <file id="F05">
        <filename>soundFile3.mp3</filename>
        <size>3.456</size>
        <length>3.23</length>
    </file>
</files>
</musicLibrary>
```

Is it possible to retrieve from the file information, for example how long the playtime is of one compilation in total, by just giving the collection id? I am really stuck with this. :/ 
I am really missing things like joins from SQL ;)

thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a problem for an XML parser.  Most languages have them, e.g. Python, Perl.

Comment: Hmm isn't it possible with XSLT and Xpath and so on? I was thinking of something like using a templates. I managed it to get all the songs of a compilation with it but I don't really know how to get it to link the FileID of the title to the id attribute of the file it self to get the total length of the compilation :( 
A join like in SQL would be really helpful :)

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked with XSLT, so I'm not sure about that.  I just know that this would be fairly trivial in almost any modern programming or scripting language.

Comment: ^^ indeed it would be but there must be a way to get it... I am actually getting really upset with myself that I am not getting it done. It looks so easy but I am not finding the clue right now. :( 
But by the way thank you for your really quick answer !!

Comment: An XSLT-based solution is pretty simple and fairly analogous to how it would be done in SQL, but using xpath predicates instead of joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with an XSLT stylesheet using xpath (you can think of it as XSLT's join equivalent). In this stylesheet, the sum of the lengths for each compilation is returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="musicLibrary">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="compilation"/>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="compilation">
        <xsl:variable name="ids" select="title/fileID"/>
        <compilation id="{@id}" title="{@title}">
            <xsl:attribute name="total-length"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(//files/file[@id = $ids]/length)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </compilation>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<compilation id="C01" title="Best of something" total-length="16.15"/>
```

Comment: Ohh you are my man!! And I was right too easy to see it;) thanks a lot u saved my night. Now I can go to sleep without tears and the thoughts of my stupidity :) 
I was thinking in a total wrong direction ;)

Comment: It goes both ways. Spend more time with XSLT and you'll forget SQL too - I know I have ;)

Comment: Hmm I can't see the great advantage of XML/XSLT and so on yet but this might be because I am totally new to it. In my opinion it is still confusing really easy things seem to be really cumbersome. But I guess the reason this am I :) Buuuuut I am still learning ^^